# Is statistical research correct if the null hypothesis is rejected AND there NO support for alternative hypothesis at the same time?

Tags: statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

I noticed that in problems about hypothesis-testing there are sometimes problmes like this: A researcher wonders if level of unemployment in city A decreased compared to previous year. S/he takes "level of unemployment is the same" as the null hypothesis and "level of unemployment decreased" as the alternative hypothesis.

What puzzles me here is that such research ignores the third possibility: in this case that level of unemployment **increased**. If unemployment really increased we will have to reject the null hypothesis, yet logically speaking the data would NOT support (if not undermine) our alternative hypothesis.  Is it just incorrect research design (like maybe the researcher should use "level of unemployment is the same OR larger" as the null hypothesis) or it's acceptable result when both null hypothesis is rejected AND the alternative hypothesis is NOT supported?

Comment: If in a one-tailed test, the evidence goes the opposite way, you will not reject the null.

Answer (score 1):

With all the usual caveats that null hypothesis significance testing is the devil, the situation you describe is what would be called a one-tailed test, where being “more extreme” means the level of unemployment decreases more, not that it changes in either direction by a greater magnitude.

If you like, you can think of the null hypothesis as being that the unemployment does not decrease. The problem with this is that you can only  compute the p value for a simple hypothesis (a single value of the parameter). So you are really just choosing the most conservative simple hypothesis within the range of the null hypothesis: that there is no impact on employment.

Comment: But what to do if data indicates that unemployment INCREASED? Under such research design how valid conclusion should sound? In comments you said, if I understood you correctly, that the null hypothesis would not be rejected. But it doesn't make sense in this scenario, our data would contradict the null hypothesis. P.S. I don't understand your "more extreme" reference.

Comment: @user161005 Way I learned it, p-value is defined as the probability under the null hypothesis that the test statistic is “more extreme” than what was observed (where what “more extreme” means depends on context). What is your definition of p value?

Comment: If your data indicates employment increased, then you probably won’t be doing a one-tailed test in the direction of decrease. If we’re being purists, we design before we collect the data, and all we guarantee is that there’s less than 5 pct chance of incorrectly rejecting the null. We put all our power to reject into the one tail, so we don’t have the privelege of rejecting the null if the data ends up being extreme in the other tail (otherwise we would be p-hacking, since we’re violating our original design to produce an effect, or choosing after the fact a design that has an effect).

Comment: If we’re not being purists, then we can just informally think of the null hypothesis we’re testing against including the case that employment increased. Of course, if we show a particularly strong evidence for increase then this is really not the best way to present this. As the first sentence of my answer suggests, I don’t really think “accepting or rejecting a null hypothesis” is a good way to think about or present results of a statistical data analysis in pretty much any circumstances.

Comment: "so we don’t have the privelege of rejecting the null" I still don't see why we can't reject the null in one-tailed test in this case. At the end we will be wrong anyway because we put our faith in the wrong result. Although I see that such one-tail "bet" has greater rejecting power than in two-tail test because our risk to be wrong is greater. "If your data indicates employment increased, then you probably won’t be doing a one-tailed test in the direction of decrease." Sounds like unethical manipulation.

Comment: "I don’t really think “accepting or rejecting a null hypothesis” is a good way to think about or present results of a statistical data analysis in pretty much any circumstances." Why?

Comment: @user161005 This was probably a bad forum for me to be opinionated on this, and definitely the wrong forum for a long discussion. I would just suggest you google around for people critical of the use of p values and nhst.. you’ll find no shortage, to the point that I feel much more a band-wagoner than an iconoclast for sharing these opinions.

Comment: @user161005 “Sounds like unethical manipulation.” This is not manipulation, but it is p-hacking, since you are deciding which analysis to do after looking at the data.

Comment: @user161005 “at the end we will be wrong anyway...” there is a difference between not affirming a positive effect and affirming a negative effect. When you have a $5\%$ significance level you are saying “ If null holds, I will only incorrectly reject the null $5\%$ of the time.” So if you waste that all in the right tail, you don’t have any more for the left tail. If you decide later to reject cause it’s extreme the other way, you’re p-hacking. (Ponder for a moment the absurdity of having strong evidence for a negative effect and not being allowed to say so.)